# WIll I pay full price on Steam publisher bundles if I already own some of the games?

Tags: steam

I was looking today at those great deals on Steam and saw the Steam's publisher bundle deal. Getting like 15 games from Square Enix for $90 is kinda sweet. But my question is if I take that bundle that have a game that I already own... will it reduce the price because I already own it or I'll have to pay the total?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try to buy one of the packs for yourself when you already own one or more of the games, the price **does not decrease** and Steam informs you that you will also **not receive extra copies** of the games that you already own.

Comment: wtf, what BS...i have such a love hate thing for steam.

Comment: You know, you could just buy each discounted game that you want individually. Steam isn't really obligated to give you even bigger discounts on whatever arbitrary subset of the pack you actually want.

Comment: no but it does make sense. hell even apple doesn't make their consumers re-buy songs with itunes if you decide to get the album. To me its just one of those feel good things.

Comment: You do realize you are complaining about increased discounts on already heavily discounted games, right?

Comment: o I don't care about a price tag, i'm talking about bundles themselves. its way more convenient to hit one button then a dozen buttons.

Comment: You don't receive giftable copies?  That sucks a bit.

Comment: I don't think it is steam that decides this but the seller of the bundle themselves?